# Unable to remove empty strings in scala list

Tags: scala, list, collections

Why none of these operations are working when I am trying to remove empty strings in my list?

This is my list:

```
(yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00409219,958193628,0305delete,800)
(yuhindmklwm00409219,959262446,0219delete,62)
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,752013801,0220delete,2700)
()
()
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85382,0126delete,500)
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,863056514,0326delete,-2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,863056514,0326delete,2700)
()
()
()
()
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85258,0313delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85012,0311delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85718,0311delete,2700)
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,744622574,0322delete,90)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,83704,0215delete,17)
()
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85253,0331delete,-2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85253,0331delete,2700)
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
(yuhindmklwm00437293,752013801,0305delete,2700)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,33165,0315delete,1000)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0319delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0219delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,85018,0118delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,90265,0312delete,6)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,02465,0312delete,25)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,857164939,0313delete,15)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,22102,0313delete,4)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,55423,0313delete,100)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,02465,0314delete,1)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,90265,0312delete,1)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,0315delete,25)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,220432304,0315delete,35)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,701211570,0315delete,35)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,28801,0315delete,10)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,0211delete,3)
(yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,02)
```

This is type of list: 
List[String] = List((yuhindmklwm00437293,93108,02)..........))

I tried filter:

```
outputList1.filter(_.isNotNull).size
```

and

```
outputList1.map(record => if (record.size>3) record) else None)
```

both these approaches are unable to remove empty strings. The size of the list remains same for both

Comment: `outputList1.filter(_.nonEmpty)` An empty `String`, i.e.`""`, is not the same thing as `null`, and `None` is not the same type as `String`.

Comment: Hi @jwvh I tried null didn't work for me, `outputList1.filter(_ != null).size` gives the same size

Comment: I _just_ commented that `null` is not the same as `""` so a `null` test won't find empty strings.

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to understand even this is not working `outputList1.map(record => if (record.size>3) record else None)` since I am just ignoring any string less than 3

Comment: `None` is not the same type as `String`. The result of that would be a mixed collection of `String`s (greater than 3 characters) and `None`s, which is not what you want. Try `filter(_.length > 3)`.

Comment: @jwvh can you please update the answer this is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165025/discussion-between-button-monkey-and-jwvh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `outputList1.filter(_.isNotNull).size`

There is no such library method `isNotNull` and if there were this isn't what you want anyway because an empty string isn't the same thing as a `null`.

Besides that, it looks like you might not be dealing with actual empty strings. The string `"()"` is not empty. It has 2 characters in it. Try `outputList1.filter(_.length > 2)` (or whatever length is your actual limit).

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach doesn't work because, as mentioned by jwvh, an empty string `""` isn't `null`. Your code only filters out null strings.

Your second approach isn't giving you the expected result (i.e. expected length of result) because you are replacing the empty records with `None`s. Replacing some items in a list with others, but not actually removing those items results in a list of the same size. `None` is an `object`, and can be one of the value of an `Option` type.

Some ways to achieve your desired result are:

1. `outputList1.filter(_.nonEmpty)`
   Simple enough, filters out empty strings.
2. `outputList1.map(record => if (record.nonEmpty) Some(record)) else None).flatten`
   A little more complex, this replaces every non empty record with `Some(<record>)` and every empty string with a `None`. The resultant List[Option[String]] (which is a mix of `Some`s and `None`s, both Option types) can be easily flattened out using `.flatten`. This will extract the value from the `Some`s, and get rid of the `None`s from the resultant list.

   3. `outputList1.collect(case record if (record.nonEmpty) => record)` Collect works similar to map, expect it doesn't throw an exception in case of a match error with it's partial function.

Comment: Are the empty strings literally `()`? If that's the case, replace `record.nonEmpty` with `record.length > 2`